# RTL8188CUS unable to install 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

Tried to compile driver from realtek. Getting following error messages.

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911.tar.gz
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/
*
*
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/clean
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8192c/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8192c ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/build M=/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: In function ‘rtw_proc_init_one’:
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
   ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
           ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_read_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
   ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
         ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:326:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("log_level", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:332:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   entry->write_proc = proc_set_log_level;
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:348:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   padapter->dir_dev = create_proc_entry(dev->name,
                     ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:379:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("write_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:385:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_write_reg;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:387:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("read_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:393:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_read_reg;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:396:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("fwstate", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:404:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sec_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:412:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mlmext_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:420:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("qos_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:427:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:434:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:441:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ap_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:448:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("adapter_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:455:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("trx_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:462:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:469:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:476:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:483:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:490:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:497:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:504:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:511:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:520:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:527:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump4", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:537:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("all_sta_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:555:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("best_channel", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:561:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_best_channel;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:564:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_signal", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:570:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_signal;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:572:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:578:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ht_enable;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:580:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("cbw40_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:586:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_cbw40_enable;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:588:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ampdu_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:594:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ampdu_enable;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:596:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_stbc", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:602:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_stbc;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:605:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("path_rssi", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:608:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("vid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:615:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("pid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:622:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rssi_disp", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:628:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rssi_disp;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:631:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sreset", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:637:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_sreset;
       ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: At top level:
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/zerberus/RTL8188C/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################"

Also tried compiling the dkms driver but getting the following error.

Building initial module for 3.13.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-36-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

i am not sure what else i can do.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Normally, you don't want to compile drivers (or kernel modules in general) yourself, but use existing binaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old driver, it won't install to Ubuntu 14.04.
You can install a driver this way:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```